# Chrome extension reload secondary tab on event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to reload a tab on user interaction, but can't figure out a solution.

I know `chrome.tabs.reload();` is the function to trigger a reload

and that `document.getElementById("...").addEventListener("click")` is able to detect user interaction, but I can't get them to work alongside each other.

.for example in the case I had `tab1` which is currently navigated to `google.com` on clicking `search` I want to trigger a event that reloads `tab2` but I can only seem to inject a trigger event on loaded pages via `content_scripts` but `content_scripts` isn't able to access `chrome.tabs.reload()`.

Attempt #1

`manifest.json`

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Hello Extensions",
  "description": "Base Level Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["reload.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

`reload.js`

```
document.getElementByClassName("gNO89b").addEventListener("click", function() {
    chrome.tabs.reload();
});
```

if I replace `chrome.tabs.reload();` in `reload.js` with `alert('example');` it works as expected, but `chrome.tabs.reload();` won't trigger.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan done :)

Comment: Simply use `location.reload()` instead.